# Unable to parse string with a dot in Java with REGEX

Tags: java, regex, vaadin7, rich-text-editor

When copy and pasting content from a word document into a Vaadin7 RichTextArea (or any other Richtextfield), there are plenty of unwanted HTML tags and attributes. Since in a current project the attribute width does some funny business, I'd like to remove them with the following funtion

```
private String cleanUpHTMLcontent(String content) {
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Cleaning up that rubbish now");

    content = content.replaceAll("width=\"[0-9]*\"",""); // this works fine
    content = content.replaceAll("width:[0-9]*[\\.|]*[0-9]*pt;",""); // not working
    content = content.replaceAll(";width:[0-9]*[\\.|]*[0-9]*pt",""); // not working
    content = content.replaceAll("width:[0-9]*[\\.|]*[0-9]*pt",""); // not working
    return content; 
}
```

The first line works fine to remove old html tags like `width="500"`, the other lines are going into the style attribute and try to remove the properties like `width:300.45pt;` with different positions of the colon.

The code works fine on the test page http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html . I generated my regex strings here, specially for java, but it's still not working. Anyone any idea?

*Here an example where it doesn't find the width property*

```
 td style="width:453.1pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
```

**UPDATE**

```
    content = content.replaceAll("width:\\s*[.0-9]*pt;",""); // doesn't work
    content = content.replaceAll(";width:\\s*[.0-9]*pt",""); // doesn't work
    content = content.replaceAll("width:\\s*[.0-9]*pt",""); // works :-)
```

it appears, that I have to escape the semi-colon as well with a backslash? I will test that

Comment: Try using `(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:pt)?)` with all of them. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ2uC9/1)

Comment: Why the vertical bar in `"[\\.|]"`?

Comment: there can be a dot or there can be no dot

Comment: @EdwinKrause: You haven't made the `decimal` part optional.

Comment: an optional dot is matched with `\\.?`

Comment: tell a case for which its not working?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I was talking about whole decimal part `.89` to be optional. I think we all know that this is just another regex in which **number with optional decimal part** is to be used.

Comment: Even if you fix the regular expressions, this is not a robust approach to solve the original problem.

Comment: It will match case like `300........4`, `300....2`

Comment: We get a bit off-topic here. The regular expression as such works, there may be more efficient ways to do it. I believe the search for the dot in the expression is the problem that it's not working in my java method

Comment: This is about removing, so you can use  `"width:\\s*[.0-9]*pt;"`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: That looks fine and the Regular Expression works fine on the test page, but in the code it doesn't find anything... Is there anything wrong with my method?

Comment: What about this one: `"(;)?width:\\d+\\.\\d+pt;"`?

Comment: Is there any non-visible space before `;`? Try `content = content.replaceAll("width:\\s*[.0-9]*pt\\s*;","")`

Comment: I leave the semicolon now in the html tags. It doesn't really hurt, nobody sees it. the important thing is that the width property is gone. Problem solved. Please write an answer with your REGEX and I will accept it as correct answer, as it solved the initial problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove any number of digits with a dot you can use a negated character class `[.\d]*` or `[.0-9]*`:

```
"\\bwidth:\\s*[.0-9]*pt;"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF2eL8/1)

The `\b` is a word boundary (makes sure we only match `width` as a whole word).

Details:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `width:` - literal string `width:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `[.0-9]*` - 0+ dots or digits
- `pt;` - literal `pt;`